# underscorejs render different results depending on environment when passing strings with colons to it

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, underscore.js

I'm running the framework Meteor based on NodeJS. When I use underscoreJS on my server I get some strange results. On the server this code returns true

```
_.contains(['s:s:s'], 's:s');
```

but in chromes inspector it returns false (as expected).

On the underscoreJS it says that they use the native indexOf internally. However this code:

```
['s:s:s'].indexOf('s:s')
```

return -1 both on my server and in the inspector (as is expected, but it seems strange that it renders different results if it really is used internally by underscoreJS.)

I'm not sure if this is caused by underscoreJS, NodeJS or Meteor.

Comment: What versions of node and underscore are you using?  This isn't happening on node 0.8.23/underscore 1.4.2.

Comment: I can't seem replicate this. I ran it on Meteor (client and server), NodeJS (with _ npm module), and in the chrome inspector and its always false. Are you doing anything else to modify underscore, how are you checking it in meteor?

Comment: @AaronDufour Underscore is of version 1.4.2 and Node is 0.8.18 (atleast that's what I have installed locally, I dont think Meteor runs its own version of Node.)
@Akshat I run `console.log(_.contains(['s:s:s'], 's:s'))` anywhere within the server directory. I havent touched the underscore lib. I first noticed the error when running `_.uniq` and some values where omitted from the returned array even though they were unique. Then I noticed `_.contains` renders the same result.

Comment: @datacarl Are you doing this testing in the node repl?  The variable name `_` is special there and won't do what you want.  If not, are you sure the values are what you think they are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to finally replicate this result. The issue is coming from underscore, it doesn't happen with version 1.4.4, but it does with 1.4.2.

Issue on github: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1044